# How to use two itemAlias in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to use two `itemAlias` in one model in my project, but when I run my program nothing appears on the browser. This is my model:

```
public static function itemAlias($type,$code=NULL) {
         $_items = array(
        'Category' => array(
            '1' => 'Administration',
            '2' => 'Faculty',
            '3' => 'Staff',
        ),
        );
                 if (isset($code))
            return isset($_items[$type][$code]) ? $_items[$type][$code] :       false;
       else
        return isset($_items[$type]) ? $_items[$type] : false;
}

public static function itemAlias($type,$code=NULL) {
    $_items = array(
        'Category' => array(
            '1' => 'College President',
            '2' => 'College Director',
            '3' => 'Dean of Student Affairs',
            '4' => 'Guidance Councilor',
            '5' => 'MArketing Head',
            '6' => 'College Registrar',
            '7' => 'College Accountant',
            '8' => 'School Nurse',
            '9' => 'Department Head',
            '10' => 'Department Coordinator',
            '11' => 'Faculty',
            '12' => 'Librarian',
            '13' => 'Property Custodian',
            '14' => 'Utility',
            '15' => 'Guard',
        ),
    );
    if (isset($code))
        return isset($_items[$type][$code]) ? $_items[$type][$code] : false;
    else
        return isset($_items[$type]) ? $_items[$type] : false;
}
```

And this is the form that uses the `itemAlias`es:

```
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'org_position'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropdownlist($model,'org_position', Organization::itemAlias('Category'), array('empty' =>'select category')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'org_position'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'org_group'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropdownlist($model,'org_group', Organization::itemAlias('Category'), array('empty' =>'select category')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'org_group'); ?>
</div>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

its a shame i just miscoded my program its possible to use two or more item aliases and you should place it under $_items array

```
public static function itemAlias($type,$code=NULL) {
$_items = array(
    'PositionCategory' => array(
        '1' => 'College President',
        '2' => 'College Director',
        '3' => 'Dean of Student Affairs',
        '4' => 'Guidance Councilor',
        '5' => 'MArketing Head',
        '6' => 'College Registrar',
        '7' => 'College Accountant',
        '8' => 'School Nurse',
        '9' => 'Department Head',
        '10' => 'Department Coordinator',
        '11' => 'Faculty',
        '12' => 'Librarian',
        '13' => 'Property Custodian',
        '14' => 'Utility',
        '15' => 'Guard',
    ),
   'GroupCategory' => array(
        '1' => 'Administration',
        '2' => 'Faculty',
        '3' => 'Staff',
    ),
);
if (isset($code))
    return isset($_items[$type][$code]) ? $_items[$type][$code] : false;
else
    return isset($_items[$type]) ? $_items[$type] : false;
}
```

i've tried it and it solves my problem thanks guys!!!